# Easy way to insert/remove attribute from specific products Woocommerce

Tags: sql, wordpress, woocommerce

i have an e-commerce with Woocommerce and i am searching an **easy way to insert and remove existing attribute from specific products**.

In particular i have many products with a specific brand (scott) and once a month i want to set attribute *promozione = interesse zero* for all scott products and after a week remove this attribute from this porducts.

How can i do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

yes you can run cron and get all products by get_posts or wp query and insert attribute like `wp_insert_term( 'red', 'pa_colors' );` with conditions and then you can get products and remove product attribute as per condition

```
$product_attributes = get_post_meta( $product->id , '_product_attributes' );

                $temp_product_attributes = [];
                foreach($product_attributes as $product_attribute) {
                    foreach($product_attribute as $pt_k => $pt_v) {
                        if ($pt_k !== $attribute_name) {
                            $temp_product_attributes[$pt_k] = $pt_v;
                        }
                    }
                }
update_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_product_attributes', $temp_product_attributes);
```

Comment: I don't understand, can you explain better, please?

Comment: you need to run a code to fetch all products and then insert attribute as per product id

Comment: not work... i fetched all products id and then i execute the function  

update_post_meta( $post_id, 'pa_promozione', 'Promo');

if i execute get_post_meta($post_id, 'pa_promozione') i see that it has 'Promo' value but when i go on Backend/Frontend i see 'Interesse Zero'... Why?

Comment: not post meta wp_insert_term( 'red', 'pa_colors' );